# What is 'Xsrf check when linking' in ASP.Net Identity/OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have created a standard ASP.Net webforms website in .Net 4.5 using Visual Studio 2015 Community edition.

I have noticed that some standard code included in above website project does some `Xsrf check` for external logins.

**Question**

I am unable to understand how this xsrf key is being used by the Identity/OWIN framework, and what is its purpose?

*Xsrf check in RegisterExternalLogin.apsx.cs*

```
else if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
 {
   // Apply Xsrf check when linking
   var verifiedloginInfo = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfo(IdentityHelper.XsrfKey, User.Identity.GetUserId());
   if (verifiedloginInfo == null)
     {
        Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login");
      }
```

*Code in IdentityHelper.cs*

```
// Used for XSRF when linking external logins
public const string XsrfKey = "XsrfId";
```